# Can using F11 “Full Screen” be captured by websites?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I know that your window size can be captured by java scrips, and CSS, and who knows what else, and is used every day against you to try and isolate your online uniqueness.

I tend to always try to use F11 to remove what I think is all the excess noise in the UI, but I just realized that I may be 1 in 10,000 that does that all the time, or that does that in some kind of predictable way during sessions.

So is this mode of viewing broadcast at all?  To be clear, can it uniquely identify me ABOVE AND BEYOND the fact that I've already maximized my window by doing it, which itself broadcasts my "unique" screen size.  At that point does hitting Full Screen mode make any difference?

Comment: i don't know the answer, but at least you can try the test on http://ip-check.info to get some informations... i wouldn't thrust the results completely, but maybe it is better than no answer at all!

Comment: Of course it can be, and a lot of other things. Via JS, mostly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an event that is triggered that javascript could detect.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange